# how to get notified when someone is playing music from iTunes' shared library?

Tags: macos, itunes, notifications

I would like to find out which of my songs are more interesting to my friends. Are there ways to get notified when someone is playing music from your iTunes' shared library? And if so, can I find out which songs or playlists they are playing? Are there ways to log this (as opposed to Growl-like notification)?